# VSIX IViewTaggerProvider for .asp

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019, vsix

I have some code in classic asp (.asp) but the visual stuio 2019 (or 2013) doesn't support visual match bracing, only match bracing with GotoBrace command ( Ctrl+ ] ).
So I decided to create a visual studio extension and modified the sample here to add support for .asp : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/walkthrough-displaying-matching-braces?view=vs-2019

But I can get it work for asp.
I created a ContentTypeDefinition for .asp and used it with no success.

```
internal static class FileAndContentTypeDefinitions
{
    [Export]
    [Name("aspwithbrace")]
    [BaseDefinition("html")]
    internal static ContentTypeDefinition hidingContentTypeDefinition;

    [Export]
    [FileExtension(".asp")]
    [ContentType("aspwithbrace")]
    internal static FileExtensionToContentTypeDefinition hiddenFileExtensionDefinition;
}

[Export(typeof(IViewTaggerProvider))]
[ContentType("aspwithbrace")]
[TagType(typeof(TextMarkerTag))]
internal class BraceMatchingTaggerProvider : IViewTaggerProvider
{
```

I tested different type for BaseDefinition like "text", "asp" "html" without success.
Extension is loaded since I can put breakpoints but it never break in constructor or functions.
Classic asp seems to be using "html (Web Forms)" type from Tool > Options > Text Editor HTML (web Forms).

Am I missing something ? Is there a another way to add my extension to the already existing asp mode ?

Answer (score 0):

In fact after cleaning solution, rebuilding it and uninstalling the extension it worked with `[BaseDefinition("html")]` but I can't tell why it didn't worked in my first tests...